# Is this "sane" to install npm v5.2.0 with node v6.11.2?

Tags: node.js, npm

Temporarily i need to have node version v6(because old gulp doesn't work with new v8x node) and npm5 (want to have better speed).

I wonder if it's good to have npm v5 with node v6. As usual i don't install/updated version of npm manually, it's installed/updated automatically together with node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine and you will see quite a performance boost when upgrading from the previous versions. Npm is just a node package manager. It will continue to work with various versions of node. The only thing that matters when using npm, with any version, is to make sure the packages you install are compatible with your installed version of node.

I am using the latest version of npm with node 6.x.x and have experienced no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Tx for the answer, i had already one issue with npm 5.3.0 that's why started to use 5.2.0 (there was strange issue other users experienced as well) (but that issue jumped on all node versions, eighter 6 & 8, but not on 7 :) )

Comment: Sounds interesting, what was the error? Seems strange that it would effect 6 and 8, but not 7.

Comment: npm i -> npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined, see
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17858

Yep, we decided to stay with node 6.11.2 & npm v5.2.0 (and yep, indeed it's very strange it works in node v7 but doesn't in v8)

Comment: Have you tried deleting your node modules folder and package.json.lock/shrinkwrap.json? When using 5.3.0? I remember having to do that once.

Comment: We removed node_modules definetely, as for shrinkwrap not sure, tried on different machines, it seems we removed it once on one machine also. Will try in future, for now will have 5.2.0. Tx, for help.